# Prove that the set $\{a^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not bounded above

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Fix $a>1$. Prove that the set $S=\{a^n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not bounded above.

We are given the hint: "First find a positive integer $n$ such that $a>1+\frac{1}{n}$ and prove that $a^n>\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\geq2$." However, I do not see how this is helpful.

**Attempt:** Assume that $S$ is bounded above. Then by the Axiom of Completeness, $S$ has a least upper bound $\sup S$ satisfying, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\sup S\geq a^n>1$. Then we have that $\sup S-1>0$, and by the Archimedean Property there exists some $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sup S>\frac{N+1}{N}$.

I have no idea where to go from here or if I am even on the right track. *I do not want a full answer*, only a hint - either one in the direction of the original hint or one that takes a different approach.

Comment: Are you sure that set is right? By considering $n = 1$, it clearly contains all of $\Bbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @TheoBendit You are correct. I have modified the question.

Comment: You must assume $a>1$, otherwise bounded by $1$.

Comment: Well then, surely you want $a > 1$, not just $a > 0$, right?

Comment: @TheoBendit again you are correct, sorry. I will edit

Comment: Umm... $1+ \frac 1n \le 2$.  So that hint is false.  And $\mathbb R^+ = \{a^1: a\in \mathbb R^+\} \subset S$ and clearly $\mathbb R^+$ is not bounded above.  And a subset of a bounded set must be bounded.  So something is *seriously* wrong with this problem as stated.

Comment: Still not true.  If $a = \frac 12$ then $\{(\frac 12)^n\}$ is bounded above by $1$.

Comment: @fleablood very sorry for all the confusion. I believe the edits now should have the problem correctly stated. $a>1$ and the hint is $a^n>(1+1/n)^n\geq2$.

Comment: And if $a \le 1$ then $a > 1+\frac 1n$ is impossible.  If $a > 1$ then $a > 1+\frac 1n$ is definitely possible but $1 + \frac 1n \ge 2$ is only possible if $n = 1$ and that is only possible if $a > 2$.

Comment: One can *never* write $x < y \ge w$.  Ever.

Comment: @fleablood sorry that was a typo

Comment: Okay... now you just need to prove $\{2^k\}$ is not bounded.  You have $a^{kn}> 2^k$.

Comment: You can use sequential approach to sole this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the hint is that for any $a > 1$ you can find an $n$ so that $a > 1 + \frac 1n$.  (Prove that can be done)

That would mean that $(1+\frac 1n)^n \ge 2$.  (Prove that) and so $a^n > (1+\frac 1n)^n\ge 2$.

So $a^{kn} \ge 2^k$.

So if you can prove that $\{2^k\}$ is unbounded you'd be done, wouldn't you?  For any $M$ there will exist an a $k$ so that $M < 2^k < a^{kn}$.

Comment: Would you mind expanding a bit on how you would show that $\{2^k\}$ is unbounded? It feels very similar to showing that the original set is unbounded, just with a particular $a$ in this case.

Comment: Well let $m = \sup \{2^k\}$ then there is a $k$ so that $m-1 < 2^k \le m$.  And $m-1 < 2^k < 2^{k+1} < 2^{k+2} < ........ \le m$.  Can you find a contradiction there?

Comment: Come to think of it, that hint is a *terrible* way to do it.  If you ignore the hint you get that if  $\{a^k\}$ is bounded above then there for any $\epsilon < \sup S$ there is a $k$ so that $\sup S-\epsilon < a^k$.  So $a\sup S -a\epsilon < a^{k+1}$  but $a^{k+1} \le \sup S$ so $\epsilon >\frac { a\sup S - \sup S}a = \frac{(a-1)\sup S}a > 0$.  That contradicts that $\epsilon$ was arbitrary.

Comment: got it, thank you very much! And, yes our professor did agree that the hint from the text was pretty bad

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $S=\lbrace a^n:n\in \mathbf{N} \rbrace $ is bounded above. Then by the Axiom of Completeness, S has a least upper bound $sup S$ satisfying, $a^n\leq supS$, for all $n\in \mathbf{N}$. Then $a^{n+1}\leq supS \Rightarrow a^n\leq \frac{supS}{a}, \forall n\in \mathbf{N}$, which gives a contradiction since $\frac{supS}{a} < supS$ as $a>1$.

Comment: How do we know that $\frac{\sup S}{a}$ is also an upper bound for $S$? Is this not necessary to reach the contradiction?

Comment: it cannot be an upper bound since $a>1$

Comment: @AlvinLepik so what is the contradiction?

Comment: @csch2 $S$ has an upper bound less than the least upper bound, which is totally not cool

Comment: @csch2 Since it is also satisfying the condition that $a^n \leq \frac{supS}{a}.\forall n\in \mathbf{N}$

Comment: @AlvinLepik, why it can not be a contradiction, you can easily see that $\frac{supS}{a}$ also becomes an upper bound of S and $\frac{supS}{a}<supS$, you can also see that $\frac{supS}{a}$ is a upper bound of $S$ as it is independent of $n$ and satisfying the condition.

Comment: @AlvinLepik, we supposed that $supS$ is least upper bound but $\frac{S}{a}<supS$ also becomes an upper bound which gives a contradiction.

Comment: @MANISHANKARPANDEY It's not me you have to convince :)

Comment: @AlvinLepik Respected sir, I have answered the question, now I am not able to understand what is the problem with this answer. It is simple approach to prove such results, using same approach many text books shows that $\mathbf{N}$ is not bounded above.

Comment: one aspect of th definition of $\sup S$ is that if anything is less than $\sup S$ then that thing is not an upper bound of $S$.  $\frac {\sup S}a$ is less than $\sup S$.  So $\frac {\sup S}a$ can not be an upper bound.

Comment: @csch2Do you still feel that my answer is not correct? If yes, then please let me know what is the problem.

Comment: @fleablood This is the contradiction I have found, since $SupS$ is least upper bound so by definition nothing less than this can be upper bound of $S$, but it is happening so we got the contradiction.

Comment: I *know* that is the contradiction you found.  So does Alvin Lepik.  We are trying to explain the contradiction to csch2.

Comment: The contradiction is in two parts. 1) For *all* $n$ we have $a^{n+1} \le \sup S$.  Thus $a^n \le \frac {\sup S}a$ *for* ***all*** $n$.  So $\frac {\sup S}a$ is an upper bound.  I think csch2 didn't understand that.  And 2) $\frac {\sup S}a < \sup S$.  And that is a contradiction.

Comment: I see the contradiction now. Thank you all for your explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Your hint does require some further effort as mentioned in answer from fleablood.

A much simpler approach is to note that $$a^n=(1+b) ^n>nb$$ where $b=a-1>0$. And clearly the result follows if one notices the obvious fact that sequence $nb$ is unbounded.